# Vue.js - search sort table with an image field

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue.js component/view  that shows the data as follows:

```
<tbody v-for="item in items">
 <tr>
 <td width="15%"><img :src="item.image"></td>
 <td width="50%">{{item.name}}</td>
 <td>{{item.purchasedate | moment(" MMMM Do YYYY") }}</td> 
 <td>${{item.price}}</td> 
 <td><a href="someurl">Item destination link</a></td> 
 </tr>
 </tobdy>
```

The data is powered by a simple axios get call that returns the items array.   I need to implement a search and sort function.  I have tried several out of box components.  Including out of box components available on NPM e.g. vue-good-table, vue-table-component, and grid-component.   There are two issues I am facing with these
1.  The image cannot be displayed and it only returns the URL
2.  Date cannot be formatted - I am using moment.js for that.

I would like to sort by name, price, and purchasedate while displaying the image. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

with vue-good-table,you can set column option like this:

```
  columns: [
    {
      label: 'photo',
      field: 'photo',
      html: true
    },
    {
      label: 'Name',
      field: 'name',
      filterOptions: {
        enabled: true,
      },
    },
    {
      label: 'Age',
      field: 'age',
      type: 'number',
    },
    {
      label: 'Created On',
      field: 'createdAt',
      formatFn: v=>moment(v).format(" MMMM Do YYYY")
    },
    {
      label: 'Percent',
      field: 'score',
      type: 'percentage',
    },
  ],
```

and data like this:

```
  rows: [
    { id:1,photo:"/static/logo.png", name:"John", age: 20, createdAt: '201-10-31:9: 35 am',score: 0.03343 },
    { id:2,photo:"/static/logo.png", name:"Jane", age: 24, createdAt: '2011-10-31', score: 0.03343 },
    { id:3,photo:"/static/logo.png", name:"Susan", age: 16, createdAt: '2011-10-30', score: 0.03343 },
    { id:4,photo:"/static/logo.png", name:"Chris", age: 55, createdAt: '2011-10-11', score: 0.03343 },
    { id:5,photo:"/static/logo.png", name:"Dan", age: 40, createdAt: '2011-10-21', score: 0.03343 },
    { id:6,photo:"/static/logo.png", name:"John", age: 20, createdAt: '2011-10-31', score: 0.03343 },
    { id:7,photo:"/static/logo.png", name:"Jane", age: 24, createdAt: '20111031' },
    { id:8,photo:"/static/logo.png", name:"Susan", age: 16, createdAt: '2013-10-31', score: 0.03343 },
  ].map(o=>({
    ...o,
    photo:`<img width="80" height="80" src="${o.photo}"/>`
  }))
```

and the result is:
[image]

Comment: I cannot define an array as shown above because my axios get calls returns the items array.     I tried mapping rows: items as well as rows: this.time but that didn't work .  While the code compiles fine it doesn't render in the browser and I see Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError:  items is undefined"

Comment: Too late - I wrote custom code on 5th to make it work.  Uninstalled good table.